# SQL query of duplicate rows filtered by max date within one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql database, "persons', that has duplicate entries based on the IDNum column. I need to query the entries and only show the rows or duplicate entries based on the newest creation date.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT IDNum
      ,PersonPGUID
      ,CreatedDateTime
      ,FirstName
      ,MiddleName
      ,LastName
  FROM [Persons]
  WHERE IDNum in (298928, 509520, 528203);
```

It returns this:

```
IDNum   PersonPGUID                             CreatedDateTime         FirstName   MiddleName  LastName
298928  C43DEB67-EB04-4066-A374-B8369D508CF6    2007-10-22 10:13:45.000 Jonathan    McKinley    Bennett-Tisdell
298928  75B63500-7C67-4B54-A2C1-F74EAF98B861    2007-10-22 10:15:35.000 Jonathan    McKinley    Bennett-Tisdell
509520  57A1FB38-93B5-4D7B-8A17-243EC9330766    2005-02-10 11:55:13.000 Lannon      Caleb       Morgan
509520  176667F4-318E-415B-AFFC-A80348325A9D    2004-08-24 06:26:27.000 Lannon      Caleb       Morgan
528203  36C372CB-C9AD-4CEC-8553-8147C7FEDE20    2009-06-08 09:26:43.000 Pedro       Trigueros
528203  5B71C0D5-10EB-4375-8F80-E8F01381E08A    2011-12-15 10:28:11.000 Pedro       Trigueros
```

I need to filter to only show on of the duplicates and it need to be the record with the MAX date for each set of duplicates.

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 3):

Try this INNER JOIN. It would give you good performance, because an inline view is used.

```
SELECT [Persons].*
FROM [Persons]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
          IDNum, 
          MAX(CreatedDateTime) AS CreatedDateTime
      FROM [Persons]
      WHERE IDNum in (298928, 509520, 528203)
      GROUP BY IDNum
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) latest_records
ON [Persons].IDNum = latest_records.IDNum AND [Persons].CreatedDateTime = latest_records.CreatedDateTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

If CreatedDateTime is an entirely unique column throughout (i.e. no two values duplicate):

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE CreatedDateTime IN
(SELECT MAX(CreatedDateTime) from Persons group by IDnum having count(IDnum) > 1)
```

Hi William,

Thanks for the 10 points, I just thought to myself that the table may also contain rows where the IdNum value is NOT duplicated. Your question shows 3 duplicate IdNum's so I don't know whether unduplicated IdNums exist within it but I assume maybe so. If so you could use this:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE CreatedDateTime IN (SELECT MAX(CreatedDateTime)
FROM Persons GROUP BY IDnum HAVING COUNT(IDnum) > 1 OR COUNT(IDNUM) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE in conjunction with windowing function to get the latest records for each `IDNum`

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
       IDNum
      ,PersonPGUID
      ,CreatedDateTime
      ,FirstName
      ,MiddleName
      ,LastName 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDNum ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC) RN
  FROM [Persons]
  WHERE IDNum in (298928, 509520, 528203)
)
SELECT IDNum
      ,PersonPGUID
      ,CreatedDateTime
      ,FirstName
      ,MiddleName
      ,LastName
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally done with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT IDNum ,PersonPGUID ,CreatedDateTime ,FirstName ,MiddleName ,LastName 
FROM [Persons] p
WHERE IDNum in (298928, 509520, 528203)
   and CreatedDateTime = (Select max(CreatedDateTime)
                          Where IDNum = p.IDNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Basically selects the max time and joins on the result

```
select * 
from persons p inner join (
      select max(CreatedDatetime) as maxTime, IDNum as maxId from persons group by IDNum) maxTimeSet
           on maxTimeSet.maxId = p.IDNum
```